# Разбить анимацию

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как разбить анимацию, чтобы сначала была скорость 1000, потом 2000, а потом вновь 1000?

```
function number_animate(){
    $(".count").each(function(){
        $(this).prop("counter",0)
        .animate({
            counter:$(this).attr("data-count")
        },{
            duration:1000,
            step:function(a){
                $(this).text(number_space(Math.ceil(a)))
            }
        })
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function number_animate(){
    $(".count").each(function(){
        for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
          setTimeout(function(){
                $(this).prop("counter",0)
                .animate({
                    counter:$(this).attr("data-count")
                },{
                    duration:( (i!=1)?(1000):(2000) ),
                    step:function(a){
                        $(this).text(number_space(Math.ceil(a)))
                    }
                })
            }, 1000); // 1000 - интервал, когда менять скорость анимации
        }
    })
}
```

Если анимация должна постоянно меняться, создаем boolean переменную и цикл:

```
function number_animate(){
    var b=true;
    $(".count").each(function(){
        while(true) {
          setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).prop("counter",0)
                .animate({
                    counter:$(this).attr("data-count")
                },{
                    duration:( (b==true)?(1000):(2000) ),
                    step:function(a){
                        $(this).text(number_space(Math.ceil(a)))
                    }
                }); b = !b;
            }, 1000); // 1000 - интервал, когда менять скорость анимации
        }
    })
}
```